# Win 10 explorer icon view aspect ratio

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons, aspect-ratio

I just upgraded from Win7 to Win10 and noticed that Explorer is stretching the icon tiles in a folder view and it looks terible.  Its distorting the image which Win7 didn't do.  Is there a way to have the Win10 Explorer show tiled images in their native aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Explorer works correctly on the machines I have here.

Make sure your screen resolution is Native and not different or stretched in any way. Restart the computer.

Now use Windows 10 Scaling (Settings, Display) to make the things on the screen bigger or smaller in proper perspective.

That works here and should work for you as well.

If you upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 in place, be sure to upgrade your Video Driver.

Comment: I have new monitors too and have the resolution set to match.  I do run 125% larger on everything to look goon on them but it should be a symmetrical scaling.  I ran a driver update already to no avail.  Snagit, word, and browsers all display correctly.

Comment: It may be the older machine (Windows 7 is quite old) is not compatible with the newer monitor and technology. Everything here including Explorer works properly with scaling.  Try scaling at 100%, native resolution, and text size at 100%

Comment: Logged out and back in.  It looks fine now.  Go figure.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome and I was happy to assist you with this.